# Excel VBA ElseIf Loop

Tags: excel, vba, loops

I am very very new to VBA, and hoping I can get some help. I have a worksheet that has the below two columns beginning at cells G:5 and H:5. I am needing to update column H based on the values from G but getting stuck. I need to go down the whole column of G and H.

| pH | Program(New Logic) |
| --- | --- |
| Deposit |  |
| Deposit |  |
| Deposit |  |
| Deposit |  |
| Pay |  |
| Card |  |
| Pay |  |

I have the below code, and tried to modify it to my needs but it doesn't populate for every cell in H as I need it to. Can anyone please look at my code and see where I am going wrong. I have my ifelse statements that seem to be correct.

```
Sub Looper()

Dim i As String
Dim Sel As String
Dim MoveDown As String
Dim pH As String
Dim Program As String

i = 2
MoveDown = "YES"

Do Until MoveDown = "DONE"
    Sel = "G5" + Replace(Str(i), " ", "")
    pH = Range(Sel).Value

 
    If pH = "Deposit" Then
        Program = "Deposit"

    ElseIf pH = "Card" Then
        Program = "Card"

    ElseIf pH = "CL" Then
        Program = "CL"

    ElseIf pH = "RE" Then
        Program = "RE"

    ElseIf pH = "Bank Op" Then
        Program = "F&C"

    ElseIf pH = "MDS" Then
        Program = "Credit Op"

    ElseIf pH = "MM" Then
        Program = "Deposit"

    ElseIf pH = "" Then
        Program = "Bankwide"

End If

    Sel = "H5" + Replace(Str(i), " ", "")
    Range(Sel).Value = Program
    i = i + 1
    Sel = "G5" + Replace(Str(i), " ", "")
    If Range(Sel).Value = "" Then
        MoveDown = "DONE"
    End If
    
Loop
End Sub
```

I first took a stab without the loop and it works but again I need this to go down the whole column:

```
Sub totn()

Dim ProductSF As String
Dim ProductNew As String

ProductSF = Range("G5").Value

If ProductSF = "Deposit" Then
ProductNew = "Deposit"

ElseIf ProductSF = "Card" Then
ProductNew = "Card"

ElseIf ProductSF = "CL" Then
ProductNew = "CL"

ElseIf ProductSF = "RE" Then
ProductNew = "RE"

ElseIf ProductSF = "Bank Op" Then
ProductNew = "F&C"

ElseIf ProductSF = "MDS" Then
ProductNew = "Credit Op"

ElseIf ProductSF = "MM" Then
ProductNew = "Deposit"

ElseIf ProductSF = " " Then
ProductNew = "Bankwide"

End If

Range("H5").Value = ProductNew

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would this formula serve your purpose? Enter it in G5 and copy down as needed.

```
=IFERROR(INDEX({"F&C","Credit Op","Deposit","Bankwide"},MATCH(G5,{"Bank Op","MDS","MM"," "},0)),G5)
```

Here's how it works, so that you can modify it to still better suit your needs.

1. The MATCH function looks for the value from G5 in this array: `{"Bank Op","MDS","MM"," "}` and returns the element number where it was found. For example, the space will be found in 4th position and the MATCH function returns 4.
2. `INDEX({"F&C","Credit Op","Deposit","Bankwide"}` holds the replacements. In 4th position is "Bankwide" and that will be returned if G5 holds a space.
3. If G5 holds a value that isn't in the MATCH array an error will result. And if an error results the formula returns the original value in G5.

Unfortunately, your two codes don't cover all possibilities. For example "Pay" has no counterpart. Therefore my formula will leave it as it is. If you want another result, add it to the MATCH array in 5th position `{"Bank Op","MDS","MM"," ","Pay"}` and add the counterpart to the INDEX array, also in 5th position, `{"F&C","Credit Op","Deposit","Bankwide","Card"}`.

Now, if you prefer to do all that with VBA you would employ the same logic. Instead of a series of IFs you would create two arrays, say you name them `Original` and `Replacement`. You would look for the item in G5 in the `Original` array and then pick the same element from `Replacement`. You would do this in a loop, like,

```
For R = 5 To Cells(Rows.Count, "G").End(xlUp).Row
    Cells(R, "H").Value = 0 ' do the conversion here
Next R
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation and time. I originally tried an =if that was much or complex then your =iferror formula. Yours works a lot better and more streamlined I appreciate it!

Comment: It appears that all is working in your formula except for blanks which should return Bankwide but instead are returning a 0. Any ideas?

Comment: A blank evaluates to an error in my formula and therefore returns the value of G5. If you want another outcome in case of blank, specify it by examining the error:- `=IFERROR(INDEX({"F&C","Credit Op","Deposit","Bankwide"},MATCH(G5,{"Bank Op","MDS","MM"," "},0)),IF(G5="",TRUE,G5))`. Replace `TRUE` with "Bankwide". Note the difference between " " (single space) in the formula and "" which is a blank.

Comment: Thank you very much this is very helpful and does exactly what I want it to! Appreciate your time.

Answer (score 0):

It is considered to be a good practice not to mix programming logic and data.

If you write data into your code like below (data is which value matches which other value) that means everytime anything has to be changed in these values you have to touch the code again.

```
If pH = "Deposit" Then
    Program = "Deposit"

ElseIf pH = "Card" Then
    Program = "Card"

ElseIf pH = "CL" Then
    Program = "CL"

' …
```

This is why this is a bad practice. Good practice is to separate code from any data, so the code logic is generic and can easily be re-used. And if data changes no programmer is needed. Also this keeps your code slim and better maintainable because it does not get messed up with a huge bunch of data.

The solution would be to write your data into a worksheet (this can be a hidden worksheet so nobody sees it and gets confused).

So if you put this into a worksheet called `MatchTable`

| Lookup | Return |
| --- | --- |
| Deposit | Deposit |
| Card | Card |
| CL | CL |
| RE | RE |
| Bank Op | F&C |
| MDS | Credit Op |
| MM | Deposit |
| =" " | Bankwide |

you can easily use a lookup formula like below in cell H5

```
=INDEX(MatchTable!B:B,MATCH(G5,MatchTable!A:A,0))
```

to pull your matching data. This formula can then be copied down to the rest of your cells.

Now any time you change something on your `MatchTable` this gets easily applied to your sheet. There is no need to touch any code or to touch any formula ever again.

Note that the formula will show an `#N/A` error if no match can be found like for `Pay` in your example. Then you can either use something like below to set a default value:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(MatchTable!B:B,MATCH(G5,MatchTable!A:A,0)),"(default, no match)")
```

Or something like

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(MatchTable!B:B,MATCH(G5,MatchTable!A:A,0)),G5)
```

to use the original value `Pay` if it doesn't match anything.

If it has to be done with VBA you can use the same combination of the [WorksheetFunction.Index method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheetfunction.index) and the [WorksheetFunction.Match method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheetfunction.match) as in the formula above within a loop using the same `MatchTable`.

Alternatively you can write the formula with VBA

```
ThisWorkbook.Worksheet("Sheet1").Range("H5:H100").Formula = "=IFERROR(INDEX(MatchTable!B:B,MATCH(G:G,MatchTable!A:A,0)),G:G)"
```

and if needed convert the formula into values then:

```
With ThisWorkbook.Worksheet("Sheet1").Range("H5:H100")
    .Value = .Value
End With
```

Comment: Thank you for this, this is helpful. The formula you provided works good. I had wanted to write it in VBA, as this is a new worksheet every time and would prefer to just run my macro each time its created.

Comment: @JC411911 Actually you can write the formula with the macro too, if that is an option for you. See my edit. So this might be an easy solution if it needs to be embedded in a VBA code.